# How do I make several radiobuttonlists so only one button can be checked from each group

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2012

Is there a way to ensure a user selecting radio buttons from a (button list) can only select one at a time from each group? I have a web form that calculates shipping cost based on weight, city and shipping method. My code isn't styled yet but this is the gist of what I'm attempting

Location         5 day delivery per pound         2 day delivery per pound
Memphis          $1.50                            $2.35
Atlanta          $2.75                            $4.50

In my form the user clicks Memphis then the button that corresponds to Atlanta for 5-day and the item weight is multiplied by $2.75 with the final cost sent to a textbox. As it is right now the user can select all the radio buttons but they are supposed to be aligned going across the form. See code below

```
<ASP Code>
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false"   
CodeFile="Default.aspx.vb" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>    
    Please select the appropriate shipping information</div>
    <div>
        <br />
        Weight of Item
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
 &nbsp;&nbsp;
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        Ship To Location
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server">
            <asp:ListItem>Memphis</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Cincinnati</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>San Francisco</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Las Vegas</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>New York</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:RadioButtonList>
        <br />
        Cost Per Pound 5-day delivery<br />
        <br />
        <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList2" runat="server">
            <asp:ListItem>$1.12</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>$0.92</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>$2.45</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>$1.21</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>$2.00</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:RadioButtonList>
        <br />
        Cost Per Pound 2-day delivery<br />
        <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList3" runat="server">
            <asp:ListItem>$1.65</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>$1.45</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>$2.70</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>$1.41</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>$2.70</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:RadioButtonList>
        <br />
        Cost Per Pound Next day delivery<br />
        <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList4" runat="server">
            <asp:ListItem>$1.92</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>$1.88</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>$3.00</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>$1.87</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>$2.99</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:RadioButtonList>
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Calculate 
 Shipping  Costs" />
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Clear Selections"  
   />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        Total Shipping Costs:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />

    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    </div>
  </form>
  </body>
  </html>

<VB Code>
Partial Class _Default
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles 
Button1.Click
    'variables to hold weight and shipping cost
    Dim itemWeight, shipCost As Double
    'get itemWeight from text box
    itemWeight = Val(TextBox1.Text)

    'memphis shipping 
    If RadioButtonList1.SelectedIndex = 0 And
        RadioButtonList2.SelectedIndex = 0 Then
        shipCost = (itemWeight * 1.12)
        TextBox2.Text = shipCost
    ElseIf RadioButtonList1.SelectedIndex = 0 And
        RadioButtonList3.SelectedIndex = 0 Then
        shipCost = (itemWeight * 1.65)
        TextBox2.Text = shipCost
    ElseIf RadioButtonList1.SelectedIndex = 0 And
        RadioButtonList4.SelectedIndex = 0 Then
        shipCost = (itemWeight * 1.92)
        TextBox2.Text = shipCost
    End If
    'cincinnati shipping
    If RadioButtonList1.SelectedIndex = 1 And
       RadioButtonList2.SelectedIndex = 1 Then
        shipCost = (itemWeight * 0.92)
        TextBox2.Text = shipCost
    ElseIf RadioButtonList1.SelectedIndex = 1 And
        RadioButtonList3.SelectedIndex = 1 Then
        shipCost = (itemWeight * 1.45)
        TextBox2.Text = shipCost
    ElseIf RadioButtonList1.SelectedIndex = 1 And
        RadioButtonList4.SelectedIndex = 1 Then
        shipCost = (itemWeight * 1.88)
        TextBox2.Text = shipCost
    End If
    'San Francisco Shipping
    If RadioButtonList1.SelectedIndex = 2 And
       RadioButtonList2.SelectedIndex = 2 Then
        shipCost = (itemWeight * 2.45)
        TextBox2.Text = shipCost
    ElseIf RadioButtonList1.SelectedIndex = 2 And
        RadioButtonList3.SelectedIndex = 2 Then
        shipCost = (itemWeight * 2.7)
        TextBox2.Text = shipCost
    ElseIf RadioButtonList1.SelectedIndex = 2 And
        RadioButtonList4.SelectedIndex = 2 Then
        shipCost = (itemWeight * 3.0)
        TextBox2.Text = shipCost
    End If
    'Las Vegas Shipping
    If RadioButtonList1.SelectedIndex = 3 And
       RadioButtonList2.SelectedIndex = 3 Then
        shipCost = (itemWeight * 1.21)
        TextBox2.Text = shipCost
    ElseIf RadioButtonList1.SelectedIndex = 3 And
        RadioButtonList3.SelectedIndex = 3 Then
        shipCost = (itemWeight * 1.41)
        TextBox2.Text = shipCost
    ElseIf RadioButtonList1.SelectedIndex = 3 And
        RadioButtonList4.SelectedIndex = 4 Then
        shipCost = (itemWeight * 1.87)
        TextBox2.Text = shipCost
    End If
    'New York Shipping
    If RadioButtonList1.SelectedIndex = 4 And
       RadioButtonList2.SelectedIndex = 4 Then
        shipCost = (itemWeight * 2.0)
        TextBox2.Text = shipCost
    ElseIf RadioButtonList1.SelectedIndex = 4 And
        RadioButtonList3.SelectedIndex = 4 Then
        shipCost = (itemWeight * 2.7)
        TextBox2.Text = shipCost
    ElseIf RadioButtonList1.SelectedIndex = 4 And
        RadioButtonList4.SelectedIndex = 4 Then
        shipCost = (itemWeight * 2.99)
        TextBox2.Text = shipCost
    End If

End Sub

Protected Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles 

Button2.Click
    For Each ctrl As Control In form1.Controls
        If ctrl.[GetType]() = GetType(TextBox) Then
            DirectCast(ctrl, TextBox).Text = String.Empty
        ElseIf ctrl.[GetType]() = GetType(RadioButtonList) Then
            DirectCast(ctrl, RadioButtonList).ClearSelection()
        End If
    Next
End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% sure what you're asking because `RadioButtonList` controls only allow one option to be selected anyway—that's what differentiates them from `CheckBoxList` controls. Do you mean you only want to allow one selection across all shipping options? As in, a user shouldn't be able to select an option from "Next-day delivery" after picking something from "5-day delivery"?

If so, add `AutoPostBack="true"` and `OnSelectedIndexChanged` handlers to the `RadioButtonList` controls and then use the VB code `(RadioButtonList1.ClearSelection())` to de-select any previous choices when a new one is clicked.

Comment: Yes, exactly. They can change the selection by choosing another option.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use a `DropDownList` control from the toolkit located in the "standard" group and set the items to "(select)", "5-Day Delivery", "2-Day Delivery", "Next Day Delivery" instead of 3 groups of `RadioButtonList` for the delivery type. Here is an example of what you can do to start with from the source code you provided us with:

ASP.NET Code:

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false"   
CodeFile="Default.aspx.vb" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>    
    Please select the appropriate shipping information</div>
    <div>
        <br />
        Weight of Item:&nbsp;
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtItemWeight" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
 &nbsp;&nbsp;
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        Ship To Location
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:RadioButtonList ID="radCity" runat="server">
            <asp:ListItem>Memphis</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Cincinnati</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>San Francisco</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Las Vegas</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>New York</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:RadioButtonList>
        <br />
        Delivery Type:<br />
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlDeliveryType" runat="server">
            <asp:ListItem>(select)</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>5-Day Delivery</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>2-Day Delivery</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Next Day Delivery</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <br />
        <br />



        <asp:Button ID="btnCalculate" runat="server" Text="Calculate 
 Shipping  Costs" />
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:Button ID="btnClear" runat="server" Text="Clear Selections"  
   />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        Total Shipping Costs:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtShippingCost" runat="server" ReadOnly="True" Width="160px"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />

    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    </div>
  </form>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Visual Basic code:

```
Partial Class _Default
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub btnCalculate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalculate.Click

        Dim dblItemWeight As Double
    Dim dblDeliveryCost As Double

        If Double.TryParse(txtItemWeight.Text, dblItemWeight) Then

            If ddlDeliveryType.SelectedIndex <> 0 Then

                ' 5-Day delivery
                If ddlDeliveryType.SelectedIndex = 1 Then

                    If radCity.SelectedIndex = 0 Then
                        dblDeliveryCost = dblItemWeight * 1.12
                    ElseIf radCity.SelectedIndex = 1 Then
                        dblDeliveryCost = dblItemWeight * 0.92
                    ElseIf radCity.SelectedIndex = 2 Then
                        dblDeliveryCost = dblItemWeight * 2.45
                    ElseIf radCity.SelectedIndex = 3 Then
                        dblDeliveryCost = dblItemWeight * 1.21
                    ElseIf radCity.SelectedIndex = 4 Then
                        dblDeliveryCost = dblItemWeight * 2.0

                    End If

                End If

                ' 2-Day delivery
                If ddlDeliveryType.SelectedIndex = 2 Then

                    If radCity.SelectedIndex = 0 Then
                        dblDeliveryCost = dblItemWeight * 1.65
                    ElseIf radCity.SelectedIndex = 1 Then
                        dblDeliveryCost = dblItemWeight * 1.45
                    ElseIf radCity.SelectedIndex = 2 Then
                        dblDeliveryCost = dblItemWeight * 2.7
                    ElseIf radCity.SelectedIndex = 3 Then
                        dblDeliveryCost = dblItemWeight * 1.41
                    ElseIf radCity.SelectedIndex = 4 Then
                        dblDeliveryCost = dblItemWeight * 2.7

                    End If

                End If

                ' Next Day delivery
                If ddlDeliveryType.SelectedIndex = 3 Then

                    If radCity.SelectedIndex = 0 Then
                        dblDeliveryCost = dblItemWeight * 1.92
                    ElseIf radCity.SelectedIndex = 1 Then
                        dblDeliveryCost = dblItemWeight * 1.88
                    ElseIf radCity.SelectedIndex = 2 Then
                        dblDeliveryCost = dblItemWeight * 3.0
                    ElseIf radCity.SelectedIndex = 3 Then
                        dblDeliveryCost = dblItemWeight * 1.87
                    ElseIf radCity.SelectedIndex = 4 Then
                        dblDeliveryCost = dblItemWeight * 2.99

                    End If

                End If

                txtShippingCost.Text = dblDeliveryCost.ToString("c")

            End If

        Else
            txtShippingCost.Text = "Please only enter numbers."
        End If
    End Sub

Protected Sub btnClear_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnClear.Click

        For Each ctrl As Control In form1.Controls
            If ctrl.[GetType]() = GetType(TextBox) Then
                DirectCast(ctrl, TextBox).Text = String.Empty
            ElseIf ctrl.[GetType]() = GetType(RadioButtonList) Then
                DirectCast(ctrl, RadioButtonList).ClearSelection()
            End If
        Next

        ddlDeliveryType.SelectedIndex = 0

    End Sub
    End Class
```

Comment: I was really hoping to use radio buttons and then play with drop down lists for another form I'm working on.